# I want to update any changes in my listview but i met with an error ANDROID

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I implement a onResume() method with a refresh code inside and i encounter an error

**This is my code**

```
// After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all events
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                adapter = new SimpleAdapter(BookmarkActivity.this,
                        eventsList, R.layout.bookmark_list, new String[] {
                                TAG_EID, TAG_ENAME, TAG_CNAME,
                                TAG_CREATED_AT }, new int[] { R.id.bk_eid,
                                R.id.bk_ename, R.id.bk_cname,
                                R.id.bk_created_at });
                // updating listView
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**This is my logcat error**

```
09-05 07:39:36.223: E/AndroidRuntime(626): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-05 07:39:36.223: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.BookmarkActivity.onResume(BookmarkActivity.java:215)
09-05 07:39:36.223: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
09-05 07:39:36.223: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3823)
09-05 07:39:36.223: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3118)
09-05 07:39:36.223: E/AndroidRuntime(626):  ... 12 more
```

How i can resolve this problem?

Comment: what is your 215 line of BookmarkActivity.java

Comment: @Shalini ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

in `((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();` the adapter object is null.... add a check that the adapter is not null before using it..

```
if(adapter != null)
    ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: ok. this is my first activity, if i go to the second activity and click the back button in the emulator, will it refresh the data?

Comment: you need to pass the new data to the adapter..and then notify it that the data was changed

Answer (score 0):

***PROBLEM*** `onResume` is called before your task is done!

Before executing this

`((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();`

check if adapter is not null

```
if(adapter!=null)
    ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i put the check already but why my listview still wont refresh when i click the back button in my emulator.

Comment: maybe because your DataSet did not change so there is no Change to show

Comment: but there is a change in my database table.